# Android Security Exception - Don't have permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: java, android, android-securityexception

Every time I try to start up my application it crashes immediately because it receives this error.

Here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simpleweatherandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:exported = "true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.simpleweatherandroid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I definitely have the permission in there and I have run out of solutions I can come up with/find on the Internet. I can't figure this out. Does anyone know what's wrong? I'm pretty new to this so it might be something basic.

Comment: add permission after `<application>` tag close and try

Comment: Whenever I try that it tells me it needs to be right under the manifest tag for it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it by from

```
    <uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

to

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also you have to clean your project and rebuild it again. Also uninstall your app from device. And finally must insure that in your mobile device internet is available.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your maniefest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

to

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```